# $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{2z^2 -5z +2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am confusing my self when computing:$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{2z^2 -5z +2}$
int the counterclockwise direction.
I have managed to factorize the denominator as: $(z-2)(2z-1)$ Giving us that the poles of the function are at $2$ and $1/2$. Both not on the unit circle. I feel I should be able to conclude that this integral is $0$.

I know that : if $f(z) = \frac{dF}{dz}$ where $F$ is analytic on an open connected set $\Omega$ and if $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $\Omega$ then: $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$

Comment: But you have a pole at 1/2... So your function isn't analytic on $\Omega\dots$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen my function is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{2 , 1/2\}$ no?

Comment: indeed. But notice Morera's theorem, which you cite at the end of your post, says you must be analytic in $\Omega, $ not that you must be analytic in $\Omega - \{\tfrac 12 \} $. Any open set $\Omega $ containing $\gamma$ will contain the point $1/2$ where your function isn't analytic, so Morera does not apply. The correct answer should involve $2\pi i. $

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I understand the issue now. How should I then approach this problem then?

Comment: if you're not familiar with Cauchy's Integral Formula or the residue theorem, use partial fractions to write the integrand as $\frac{1}{3(z-2)} - \frac{2}{3(2z-1)}.$ The integral over the left fraction DOES dissappear by Morera's Theorem, and you should hopefully know that integrating $\frac{1}{z-a}$ about a circle containing $a$ gives $2 \pi i. $ If you don't, use the definition of the complex integral to prove that. Super pivotal fact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy's integral formula $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{2z^2 -5z +2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\frac{dz}{(z-2)}}{{z-\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{1}{2}2\pi i \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-2}=\frac{-2\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this as a reference when I study Cauchy Integral formula

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you already know it.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I know that : if $f(z) = \frac{dF}{dz}$ where $F$ is analytic on an open connected set $\Omega$ and if $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $\Omega$ then: $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$

That is false. It becomes true if you say **simply** connected. If you delete a point from an open set in the plane, the remaining set is not simply connected.

If the curve winds once counterclockwise around a region within which there are simple poles, then each simple pole makes a nonzero contribution to the value of the integral. Look up Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Interesting... I will have to spend more time on this theorem. Thank you!